# How to fix fail after instaling r9 280x on 17.1 (artful)

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I have tried to look, but could not find a situation that was similar to my problem, but it might be due to my inexperience in Ubuntu.

I have a computer which I recuperated that I did a clean install of the latest version of Ubuntu, 17.1. It was working flawlessly. I decided to install a new graphic card a r9 280x from gigabyte.

Now the computer boot, but I can get no further. I modified the bios so that i could still see what was happening through the iGPU output and I get a weird window. (Well weird for me). Basically its a list of thing with [ok] beside each element. One of them is [failed] and says "Failed to start Load Kernel Modules". It says I am in "Emergency mode" and then i can press enter to get into some kind of terminal.

If I remove the card everything revert to normal and it boot flawlessly.
The computer is a i5-2400 on an asus motherboard with the h61 chip if it helps

I have not touched the drivers of anything because i read that the opensource driver on Ubuntu should be able to at least make the card work, if not very well.

Since I know nothing of Linux and Ubuntu, what would be the proper course of action from this point?

Comment: Are you able to boot into the recovery mode from grub? You might be able to install the proper driver from there.

Comment: I am unsure about what grub is, but on subsequent reboot I was able to select "Ubuntu advanced" for boot and select a recovery mode. There I was greated to a pink screen with options. I asked it to see it it could fix broken files. I tried to allow network and then install the padoka stable driver, which i read are appropriate for my card. However i could not as it sais user does not exist. Then i rebooted and suddently I was able to get Ubuntu to load normally. I am unsure about what happened.

Comment: those options, which include Ubuntu Advanced, are in grub. It's what points your computer towards where you boot from. It saying user doesn't exist is odd, unless you deleted it somehow by accident. Were you able to install the Padoka/Oibaf drivers when you booted normally?

Comment: I am trying to install them as we speak, however I'm hitting the no ultimately trusted key found, which I suppose is an altogether different problem. This is quite a harsh world for the new ubuntu user.

Comment: It sure is. Rough learning curve, I'd imagine. That error just means you added the PPA for Padoka's drivers incorrectly, or there's something wrong with them; in this case, it looks like Padoka's drivers don't support 18.04 yet (which I know you're on artful, but still). Try Oibaf's: `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers && sudo apt-get update`

Comment: I think I actually managed to install them. I am unsure however how to check if i did. Also, It is my first time on this website, what would be the proper way to show my appreciation for your great help.

Comment: Don't worry about it! These are only comments, so the most there is is an upvote, if you hover to the left of the comment.